# Laravel Command Error in Inserting Data to database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services

I am creating a web app that has Laravel Voyager as its backend side. From there, I can manipulate data to the database without a problem. And now I created a command by running `php artisan make:command` that will insert data to the database

This is my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use DateTime;
use DB;
use App\CronTest;


class SampleCron extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'sample:cron';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Sample CRON';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $datetime = new DateTime(); 
        $timestamp = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        // DB::table('cron_tests')->insert([
        //     'name' => $timestamp
        // ]);

        CronTest::create(['name' => $timestamp]);
    }
}
```

This is my CronTest.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CronTest extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ["name"];
}
```

so everytime I will run `php artisan sample:cron` it will insert a `$timestamp` to the database. There's no problem in my local machine since I used Docker to run this project. But in my Dev Server which in Amazon Web Service (AWS), I separated the DB in RDS for security purposes. What happened now is that the `php artisan sample:cron` command will return error

This is the error

```
In Connection.php line 664:

  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mydb.cro  
  n_tests' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `cron_tests` (`name`, `updated_at`  
  , `created_at`) values (2018-11-14 06:31:19, 2018-11-14 06:31:19, 2018-11-1  
  4 06:31:19))                                                                 


In PDOConnection.php line 79:

  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mydb.cro  
  n_tests' doesn't exist                                                       


In PDOConnection.php line 77:

  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mydb.cro  
  n_tests' doesn't exist
```

I checked my RDS DB using MySQL Workbench and tried to run sql query `mydb.cron_tests` and it is there. I actually copied my DB in local and import it to RDS.

Does anyone know how this error occured? Thank you!

Comment: pl again check table is there or not  and also check database connection string

Comment: check your env file/config, maybe you're connecting to the wrong database server.

Comment: @JigneshJoisar I copied the credentials I used in workbench and check it again just now as what you've told but it's all in the same strings.

Comment: @Joe the env file in my laravel project has the same connection string with my credentials in mysqlworkbench

Comment: can u try this command `php artisan config:cache` and `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: @JigneshJoisar okay I will do it now

Comment: @JigneshJoisar still the error occurred

Comment: @Imperatura show ur CronTest model .

Comment: @JigneshJoisar I edited the post and added the CronTest model

Comment: i think database created by migrate command so try to php artisan migrate

Comment: @Krishnakushwaha I made the database inside Laravel Voyager, I just wonder why it worked in my local machine but not in dev server

Answer (score 0):

instead of `use App\CronTest;`
use the `use App\Models\CronTest;`